# [ios-X] versus [iosX]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

While re-tagging a question, I noticed the tag for specific versions of iOS is as such [ios4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios4). Is there any reason for this?

I personally think [ios-4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-4) would be cleaner. Besides, we already have [ios-sdk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-sdk) and [ios-appstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-appstore)

Is it possible to retag the ios tags following this logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I'd like to change:

- [ios4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios4) to [ios-4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-4)
- [macbookpro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro) to [macbook-pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook-pro)
- [macpro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macpro) to [mac-pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-pro)
- [macbookair](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbookair) to [macbook-air](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook-air)
- maybe even [osx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) to [os-x](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-x)

and so on. Oddly, [mac-mini](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini) is already in this format, which is one of the reasons the ones that aren't annoy me.

Comment: I agree on all you want except osx.

Comment: I agree with @am1, that would be a nice cleanup before going live.

Comment: agreed... i'd say everyone just start fixing them as they have time, we don't seem to have any dissent

Comment: @cala it's better use tag synonyms.

Comment: @cala, don't you mods have a renaming tool for that sort of thing? The kind that don't bump the retagged questions to the top.

Comment: @Am1rr3za: good point. @Loic: yes, but for some reason I wasn't thinking of synonyms :)

Comment: I did all the ones @Dori listed other than osx.  Plus the other iosx tags (4.2, 3).

Comment: I think that we should try to have the tag as close to the actual product name as possible. For example, mac-os-x instead of osx.

Comment: @calavera I think it's better to change windows7 tag to windows-7 too.